# Guardar datos en una aplicacion ingresados por el usuario

Tags: java, android

Existe alguna forma para que, por ejemplo en una encuesta, el usuario responda una serie de preguntas, y luego de click en "Enviar encuesta", después haga click en "Encuestas" y aparezca la informacion que puso en la encuesta anterior. Asi sucesivamente, pero que cuando la aplicación se cierre y vuelva a abrir, no se pierdan los datos. Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Actualmente este es el código que tengo:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                EditText preg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText preg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                RadioButton botonun = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
                RadioButton botondo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
                RadioButton botontr = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
                RadioButton botoncu = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
                RadioButton botonci = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
                RadioButton botonse = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
                RadioButton botonsi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
                RadioButton botonoc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
                RadioButton botonnu = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
                RadioButton botondi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
                RadioButton botonon = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
                RadioButton botondc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
                String strNombre = nom.getText().toString();
                String strPregCinco = preg5.getText().toString();
                String strPregCuatro = preg4.getText().toString();

                if(strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") || strPregCuatro.matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"¡Dejaste campos vacíos!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if(botonun.isChecked() == false && botondo.isChecked() == false && botontr.isChecked() == false && botoncu.isChecked() == false && botonci.isChecked() == false
                        && botonse.isChecked() == false && botonsi.isChecked() == false && botonoc.isChecked() == false && botonnu.isChecked() == false && botondi.isChecked() == false
                        && botonon.isChecked() == false && botondc.isChecked() == false)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste algunas respuestas!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(pas);
                }
            }

        });
```

Los RadioButton son preguntas de seleccion multiple, y los EditText son preguntas abiertas, entonces, en el mainactivity tengo estos botones:

```
<Button
    android:text="Resultados profesores"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/encuesta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="0dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Resultados 11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
android:text="Resultados 9"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Resultados 8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

La idea de esto es un proyecto escolar, de una aplicacion donde se encuestan estudiantes de varios cursos sobre la movilidad, y despues, haces click en "Resultados 8" y te aparecen todos los resultados de los estudiantes de grado 8.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo implementar el sistema de bases de datos en mi aplicacion para que funcione de dicha manera?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Al realizar encuestas regularmente se tiene un concentrador para explotar la información, el obtener y guardar los datos se realiza mediante un web service. Lo comento por **si esto lo deseas realizar local puedes guardar datos en tu aplicación pero no tiene ningún sentido si esta información no se concentra en algún lugar externo a la misma**.

Como ejemplo:
http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101

Si lo que deseas es almacenar datos en el dispositivo revisa la documentación.

[Android : Cómo guardar archivos](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=es)

Comment: Mi idea es guardar los datos en la aplicacion, pero guardarlo en una página web es lo que no deseo, ya que esto es un simple proyecto de colegio. Igualmente gracias!

Comment: Las opciones de almacenamiento pueden ser varias, Base de datos, archivos, preferencias, agreguè el documento en mi respuesta.

Comment: Vale, pero despues de que se almacenan las respuestas de la encuesta, como puedo mostrarlos en una nueva activity?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas son los [opciones de almacenamiento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) en Android. La documentación oficial ya esta traducido a español.

Si tienes pocos datos para almacenar, como un `String encuesta`, puedes usar los `SharedPreferences`. Para cargar los resultados guardados (si anteriores existen) por ejemplo en `onCreate` usas:

```
  SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences();
  // el siguiente código te carga el valor guardado o "" si no hay nada guardado todavía
  String encuesta = pref.getString("encuesta", "");
```

y cuando recibes datos de una encuesta:

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
  editor.putString("encuesta", encuesta);
  editor.commit();
```

Para datos más complejos puedes revisar las opciones para almacenamiento interno o externo, o acceder a una base de datos SQLite (todas documentados en el enlace).

En el caso de guardar tus datos en una bbdd SQLite, puedes implementar un [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) y desde eso obtener la bbdd usando `getWritableDatabase()` o `getReadableDatabase()` (para solo lectura).

Comment: Hey amigo gracias!! actualmente tengo este código:

Comment: Viendo la otra respuesta me entra la duda, estas buscando algo como un cookie?

Comment: No se a que te refieres con un cookie, lo que deseo es que, cuando la persona responda las preguntas, de click en el boton "Enviar Encuesta", y cuando haga click en el boton "Resultados" aparezca lo que esa persona escribió. En la misma aplicacion, y que cuando se cierre la aplicacion y se vuelva a abrir, no se pierda ningun dato.

Comment: La pregunta mas simplificada, es: que puedo hacer para que los datos que ingresen los encuestados, se guarden en las variables que definí en encuesta.java, y que dichas variables se muestren en la activity que se abre al pulsar "resultados 8"

Comment: Ya entendí de tu comentario en la otra pregunta y con lo que agregaste a tu pregunta que prefieres guardar los datos localmente (que es tu libre decisión, aun que si es cierto que tuviera más sentido de guardar los datos centralizados en un caso de encuestas). Una respuesta completa para guardar tu encuesta en una base de datos es un poco amplio para el contexto de stackoverflow, pero el enlace que te dí en la respuesta más los ejemplos bloque de notas y diccionario (lo encuentras en los ejemplos de Android Studio) te dan una buena base para implementarlo.

Comment: Es que sinceramente ya habia leido esa documentacion, pero no entendi mucho. Igualmente lo volveré a leer, pero si puedes, porfavor echame una mano con esto. Gracias!

Comment: Empieza con implementar un `SQLiteOpenHelper`, si es necesario, lee un poco sobre SQLite, no es necesario de usar la documentación de Android para eso, y diseña tus tablas. Te vas a dar cuenta que no es tan difícil. Si algo no te resulta, actualiza tu pregunta, o haz una nueva si es un tema mucho más especializado (o ya no cuadra con la pregunta original).

Comment: Vale, empezaré a mirar sobre eso. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Una ultima cosa, donde puedo implementar el SQLiteOpenHelper? Justo en la activity donde quiero que se muestren los resultados? O simplemente puedo crear una nueva clase de java, y crearlo alli?